# Best practice : What instead of "User-Agent" in http headers to identify an app?

Tags: http-headers

It looks like you can't always set "user-agent" header using Ajax. (user-agent is somewhat a reserved keyword and you can't forge it on some browser because of security concern).

When calling my REST service I'd like the caller to give me a clue about who (which application) is using it.
Registration won't be mandatory, it's rather a way to check if there are some external (valuable) clients that still use my web service when I'd like to close it.

**So if I can't use the "user-agent" is there some name of choice to use instead ?
X-Application-Id ? X-UserAgent ?**

Is there some doc that lists all those X-*** headers ?

Comment: About the `X-...` prefix, I think the idea is being able to make up yours.

Comment: Too much choice : ) Is there a de facto standard for such a use ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, it may or may not be possible to add custom headers to your application.

From your question, I assume that you are able to set custom headers. The default for your application would be to use the User-Agent Flag as described in the [Official HTTP Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-46):

> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system use.  A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each request unless specifically configured not to do so.

If you choose to add another custom header, there are no restrictions or recommendations for the name of the header. Please note, that you should not use an "X-" prefix as described in [RFC 6648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6648):

> Historically, designers and implementers of application protocols have often distinguished between standardized and unstandardized parameters by prefixing the names of unstandardized parameters with the string "X-" or similar constructs.  In practice, that convention causes more problems than it solves.  Therefore, this document deprecates the convention for newly defined parameters with textual (as opposed to numerical) names in application protocols.

Comment: Yes I can set custom headers. But some browsers (some version of chrome) don't allow you to set the "user-agent" one.

Comment: [Wikimedia requires `Api-User-Agent`](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy#JavaScript) for bots that cannot set `User-Agent` (in the browser)